# T o' clock at $T^2$ Miles

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A bicycle travels along a straight road. At t o' clock it is $t^2$ miles from the end of the road. Compute its average velocity from 1:00 to 4:00; and instantaneous velocity at 3:00.

Answer for first part is 5mi/hr.
Answer for second part is 6mi/hr

I thought it would be easy cuz all you have to do is count the number of hours. which is $3$;

$3^2$ corresponds to miles traveled so its simply 9. $\frac{dx}{dt} = 3$ hours over 9 hours is 3mi/hr.

I also try $\frac{v1-v2}{2}$; v1 = 1; since $1^2$ miles over 1 o'clock and $v2 = 3mi/hr$ since $3^2$ miles over 3 o'clock...

What am I doing wrong? I know I have to use calculus but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that your question indicates that the displacement $s(t)=t^2$.

To find the average velocity from $t=a$ to $t=b$, calculate $\frac{s(b)-s(a)}{b-a}$

To find instantaneous velocity at $t=c$, compute $s'(c)$.